# looping through 1 million records update with where VS update sql with where IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, performance, where-clause

I have table of more than 2 million records..

I may need to update ; say 1 million records;

which is more efficient between below two:

1. Looping through million records and run update query with where id=id million times ?

or

2. get all million ids and implode it ; and use it in single update query with WHERE id IN (id1,id2,.....id100000)

Can any experts help me with this?

Comment: a. benchmark 1, b. benchmark 2, compare a to b, profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the option 1 you are suggesting will be slower than the option 2, however the option 2 will eat a lot more memory and could potentially block your table for few minutes ...

it really depends on your DB architecture, and the context (is it on a Dev or Prod server? is it an operation you'll need to repeat ? etc.), but I would opt for a third option :

3. **update by batch:** For instance, you could update 10000 rows per 10000 (update the first 10000 rows, then the next 10000 rows, etc...)

10000 is obviously an example and, as suggested by Dagon in his comment, you should test the different options if you can.

---

Note : concerning your option 2, you should consider a better WHERE clause than ALL the IDs you want to update in an IN (you could for instance use the same conditions you'd use here : "*get all million ids and implode it ;*")